# Seeking interactive maps and associated technologies

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

The display of maps and data within an interactive framework is becoming more prevalent online. I'm thinking beyond merely the ability to pan/zoom/control layers, but more along the lines of displaying spatial and non-spatial data, together, in a unique format (e.g. animated charts).

For example, [this website](http://www.watershed-watch.org/fraser-basin-livemap/) goes beyond mapping and presents spatial data as a learning and exploration tool with graphical data summaries, text summaries, animations, etc.

What are some good examples of well-designed interactive maps using modern technologies, and what are the advantages/disadvantages of these tools?

What technologies should be avoided?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

This is a very dynamic and exciting period for interactive data and map applications on the Web. This great dynamism is driven (but to some extent also drives) by the numerous innovations and trends that are currently undergoing within the complex Web scenario (users, industry, standards, innovation...). Very briefly:

1. Browsers are getting more and more capable, with JavaScript interpreters becoming faster and [HTML5 technologies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) getting more widely adopted.
2. To some extent, different browser vendors are finally converging more towards a wide adoption of Web Standards. A relevant example for data and mapping visualizations is SVG that, although around as a Web standard since 1999, lacked until recently wide adoption, because of Internet Explorer not supporting it until version 9.

The consequences of this are that JavaScript is becoming central to building today's Web applications and functionality is moving from the server to the client wilts the 2 are becoming more decoupled with the rise of REST interfaces. This is well exemplified, for example, in the rise of so many JavaScript MVC frameworks or even more by the huge proliferation of Open Source JavaScript libraries and projects on well known code repository sites such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

If JavaSript (and HTML5) is the big winner, Flash is the loser. You can still find Flash applications around the Web (your example is a beautifully designed interactive Flash application), but its technology is clearly PAST.

#### Companies that are doing some serious JavaScript data-map Web visualizations:

- [vizzuality](http://vizzuality.com/). These guys from Spain are amazing. There interactive visualizations are stunning. They also have a Web product called [cartodb](http://cartodb.com/) that lets you upload data to a PostGIS server and create awesome visualizations. And look out also their [HTML5 mapping experiments](http://vizzuality.github.io/HTML5-experiments/), to have an idea of where the technology is heading.
- [MapBox](http://www.mapbox.com/) is another awesome company that drives a lot of innovation in the Web mapping-data visualization field. [Tilemill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/), in particular, based on [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) and JavaScript and Web technologies, is something ESRI would have never had the creativity to invent.
- [Stamen](http://maps.stamen.com/), not my personal favorite, but still very good and full of innovative ideas.

#### About and around d3.js:

- [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) is by far the best example of a JavaScript library built for data and map interactive visualizations. The links could be endless here.
- [Map gallery list](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery#maps)
- [Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/) Web page.
- [Jason Davies](http://www.jasondavies.com/)
- [Geo-Projections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections)
- [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson)

#### Other great JavaScript technologies:

- [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/). Simply beautiful maps and visualizations.
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). Years ago, when flash was still strong, it opened the road to Open Source JavaScript mapping.
- [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/). One cannot avoid mentioning this library for its huge following among today's Web designers and programmers.

#### And Web examples:

- [protectedplanet](http://protectedplanet.net/), an original and nice way of making use of google maps.
- [remittances](http://remittances.herokuapp.com/?en), a nice d3 example from the above gallery.
- [MapMaker Interactive](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/mapping/interactive-map/?ar_a=1). I love the idea behind this, but the implementation is far from perfect.

Answer (score 2):

A List of 'OpenSource' GIS & **WebMap Servers**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software

Recommend Geoserver 2.1
http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Stable