# Possibilities to integrate vector and raster files within a webmap

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, openlayers, web-mapping, web-gis

How can vector and raster (georeferenced image) data be integrated within a webmap (Leaflet, OpenLayers) and which infrastructure/architecture (Server, Database) is required?

As far as I know these ways are possible - please help me complete the list.
Is it any time really required to use a database?

Vector data:

- GeoJSON: only requires a text file
- Web Feature Service (WFS): requires a published WFS placed on a GeoServer?

Raster data:

- Web Map Service (WMS): requires a published WMS placed on a GeoServer?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question and, in any event, questions seeking lists of answers are not suited for focussed Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely get away without a database if you use GeoJSON files or similar portable web formats, and a tiling service.  GeoServer, MapServer, ArcMap, and more are great options for tiling your raster data.

On the vector side, you have things like GeoJSON, TopoJSON, etc., but you also have options to get more complex by using tools like PostGIS to do database level calculations and generate these vector files dynamically if you need that.

What you're asking for is really a list of all available web mapping technologies and compatible formats.

There is an older question that addresses some of this at: [Seeking interactive maps and associated technologies?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64051/good-examples-of-interactive-maps-and-associated-technologies)

But obviously the field has evolved a bit since then.